# How can I access to the style class of the title in header of Navigation Drawer?

Tags: css, javafx, navigation-drawer, gluon, gluon-mobile

I would like to change the text color of the title of the header using css classes but I m not able to find the selector.
I have tried many combinations like for example but It didn't work:
`.navigation-drawer > .header > * > .label { -fx-text-fill:white; }`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYTdD.png)

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74080036/3956070

Comment: can you post some pictures to let us easy to understand?

Comment: @JoséPereda I think the scenic view doesn't work Mac M1. I am receiving error:
„libjvm.dylib“ Cannot Be Opened Because the Developer Cannot be Verified.

Comment: @yab I attached a picture. Actually I would like to change the title's color from black to blue for example.